# Convert datagramPacket to String

Tags: android, mdns

I want to create an android application that can capture MDNS advertisement send by a device connected to my network.
I want to get the response as

```
NOTIFY * HTTP/1.1
HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
CACHE-CONTROL: max-age = seconds until advertisement expires
LOCATION: URL of the web page to advertise
NT: urn:physical-web-org:device:Basic:1
NTS: ssdp:alive
SERVER: OS/version UPnP/1.0 product/version
USN: advertisement UUID
```

Can anyone help me to convert response like above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this  code

```
buffer = new byte[1024]; 
packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
socket.receive(packet);
buffer = packet.getData();
String packetAsString=new String(buffer, 0, packet.getLength());
Log.d("DatagramPacket","Received: "+packetAsString);
```

see this link [Datagrampacket to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557132/datagrampacket-to-string)

Comment: getting like Received: ����������������������106243231in-addrarpa������